How to stop VSCode's gutter from changing size
Is there a way to make the VScode gutter a constant width? I have a few extensions that use a gutter icon (along with the breakpoints) and they are often changing, which changes the size of the gutter, which causes my code to jump back and forth.
I'd rather have my gutter stay a little bigger than it needs to be, or even not enlarge when new icons show up.
